# LTC 1060 switched capacitor filter in mode 3: why this output forms:

Tags: filter, ltspice, switched-capacitor

So I'm simulating a switched capacitor filter using LTC in mode 3. Here is my schematics:

[image]

Now I'm performing a transient analysis with a 3V sinusoidal voltage with frequency 1.4 kHz and a 3V square wave with frequency 250 Hz. However I don't understand my results. The sinusoidal one is way off, while the square wave is while more acceptable I don't get what is going wrong. Can someone please help me understand this?
My results:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your circuit has gain and the output is hitting the limits it can produce. Try lowering your input signal amplitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [the datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1060fb.pdf) for guidance.  The output is only specified to sink 3mA, and you're limiting at about 3V above the negative rail, into a 1\$\mathrm{k}\Omega\$ resistor.  In other words, you're limiting at the point where the output is asked to sink 3mA.

Try resizing resistors as necessary so that the output resistors are no less than 5\$\mathrm{k}\Omega\$ (the data sheet implies that 5\$\mathrm{k}\Omega\$ is the lowest "good" value to use -- I'd consider 10\$\mathrm{k}\Omega\$ or more).